# How do I flip the bits of ord('a')

Tags: perl

How do I flip the bits of ord('a')? I tried this and it looks correct but I'd like the experts to chime in. Note: This is a ascii text 'a'.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

printf "0x%07b\n", ord('a');
printf "0x%07b\n", (~ord('a')) & (0x7f);

exit(0);
```

Comment: [Tutorial bitwise_operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/bitwise_operators_example.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~` is indeed the bitwise negation operator. Perl integers are 32- or 64-bit in size depending on your build of Perl, so you are finding the bitwise negation of the number returned by `ord('a')` (`0x61`). You proceed to use the bitwise AND operator to clear all but the 7 least significant bits of those 32/64.